# angular Module '"C:/xxxxx/customNgbDateParserFormatter has no exported member CustomNgbDateParserFromator

Tags: angular

I created a custom class using help from [NgbDatePicker - How to bind longDate string to [ngModel]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658935/ngbdatepicker-how-to-bind-longdate-string-to-ngmodel). 
Instead of MyNgb... I directly in Vs Code using right click--> create file--> name it customNgbDateParserFormatter although when you open file The Class name is CustomNgbDateParserFormatter. Then, i added this as a provider in app.module.ts as below . On compilation, I am getting below error: Module C:/users....customNgbDateParserFormatter has no exported member 'CustomNgbDateParserFormatter'
App.module

```
  import {NgbModule, NgbDateParserFormatter} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng- 
     bootstrap';
  import { CustomNgbDateParserFormatter } from './custom- 
  screen/customNgbDateParserFormatter';

 providers: [{provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useFactory: () => new 
   CustomNgbDateParserFormatter('longDate')}],
```

Comment: So do you have global `export class CustomNgbDateParserFormatter {}`?

Comment: I am not sure if wrong with the file creation- bcoz i didn't define any filename.component.ts or filename.service.ts. I simply put ts file. Am I suppose to create it like component or service as I just want to use it like a utility class.

Comment: export class CustomNgbDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

Comment: I have copied exactly same as in the other stackflow link except i just changed the name of the class.